# RxJS Dropping duplicate requests

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

When fetching posts, some posts may be by the same user, thus fetching the same user multiple times is redundent. A post has the following:

- `userId`
- `id`
- `title`
- `body`

Here's my `users` epic:

```
const fetchUserEpic = (action$, store) =>
    action$
        .ofType(UsersActions.FETCH_USER)
        .mergeMap(action => {
            const users = store
                .getState()
                .usersStore.get('users')
                .toJS()

            // Check whether user is already in the store
            if (users[action.payload]) {
                return of(UsersActionCreators.loadCachedUser())
            }

            // Fetch user (and catch errors)
            return ajax
                .getJSON(URL + '/users/' + action.payload)
                .map(res => UsersActionCreators.fetchUserFulfilled(res))
                .catch(err => of(UsersActionCreators.fetchUserRejected(err)))
        })
```

With my current epic, for the initial `fetch` of the posts, my caching won't work, but only for later requests.

I believe that my epic should keep only the first request for the (same!) user and drop the rest, until the user is fetched. If there's a better strategy please suggest.

Comment: you're referencing state within an effect which is generally bad form and produces bad results.  You should restructure things so that the payload contains the cached users and you check the cache that way.

Comment: @bryan60 So if I dispatch `FETCH_USER` within some component's `componentDidMount`, should I also check there whether the user already exists? (instead of in the epic)